# import python module in WLST (weblogic scripting tool)

Tags: python, weblogic, python-module, wlst

I need to import python modules in WLST. For example I need "signal" module in WLST to write a timeout function. So I ask you how to do that.

Environment:
Oracle Linux 6,
Oracle Weblogic 11

Moreover, I let you see a piece of code in WLST where I need a timeout function at the and of what it raises an exception:

```
import sys
import os
from java.lang import System
import getopt
import time as systime

[...]

def _startServer(ServerName):
    while(true)
        try:
            cd('domainRuntime:/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/'+ServerName);

            cmo.start();
            state=_serverstatus(ServerName);
            while (state!='RUNNING'):
                state=_serverstatus(ServerName);
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000);

            #=================
            # timeout function
            #=================

        except:
            print 'Error in getting current status of ' +ServerName+ '\n';
            print 'Please check logged in user has full access to complete the start operation on ' +ServerName+ '\n';

            os.popen('sh /home/oracle/scripts/logAnalytics.sh')
            systime.sleep(60)

            exit()
        break

[...]
```